# Decrypt a bouncycastle(java) encrypted string on Swift 2

Tags: java, swift, encryption, bouncycastle

I am currently creating an app which reads a QR code and displays the details about it. An encrypted QR string data is used to create the QR code. The QR string data was generated using the bouncy castle api via the Grain-128 engine. I've been researching how to decrypt the said string data using swift 2 to no avail. Any help will be welcome.